# How do I make a button in my tk UI that makes the program do a whole ton of stuff when it is pressed not freeze the window?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm just getting started with Tk and using it in python.  I set up a button that does a ton (like two minutes worth) of stuff behind the scenes when you press it.  I also set up a status text to show what's going on while this is happening.  I set it up like this:

```
status_text = Tkinter.StringVar()
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Stats!", command=go).grid(column=1, row=4)

def go(*args):
    status_text.set("Logging in...")
    do_lots_of_stuff()
    status_text.set("Doing stuff #1...")
    do_even_more_stuff()
    status_text.set("Success!")
```

The problem is that when you press that button the window freezes, and the status text never actually changes.  It looks broken, and doesn't come out of this state until all the processing finishes 2-3 minutes later. How do I make it not freeze and update the status text?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I monitor Tkinter buttons when Python is busy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376870/how-can-i-monitor-tkinter-buttons-when-python-is-busy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's time to learn multithreading!

What's happening is that the GUI (main thread) is waiting for the method to return so that it can continue updating the interface.

You'll want to cause the action of a button to spawn a `threading.Thread` instead of running the heavy code in the main thread. You'll also want to create a Queue to access the data from the other thread (since sending GUI requests should ONLY be made from the main thread).

```
import threading, Queue #queue in 3.x

my_queue = Queue.Queue()

def go(*args):
    my_thread = threading.Thread(target=function_that_does_stuff)

def function_that_does_stuff():
    my_queue.put("Logging in...")
    do_lots_of_stuff()
    my_queue.put("Doing stuff #1...")
    do_even_more_stuff()
    my_queue.put("Success!")
```

Then you'll need a function that is run when the update event happens.

```
def OnUpdate(*args):
    try:
        status_text.set(my_queue.get())
    except Queue.Empty:
        pass
```

Comment: One question: in this case, when does OnUpdate() actually get called?

Answer (score 1):

If you have control of `do_lots_of_stuff` and you can break it into small chunks,  you can place small jobs on the event queue to do each chunk.

For example, if you're `do_lots_of_stuff` is reading lines from a file, create a method that reads one line and then puts a job on the event queue to call itself after a ms or two. This way the event loop continues to run, and your code does a little processing on each iteration. This is a surprisingly effective technique, though it only works if you're able to break your 'lots of stuff' into atomic chunks.

If you can't do that you'll have to either use multiple threads or multiple processes. I personally prefer the latter -- multiprocessing code is (arguably) less difficult to write and debug.