# Why my Tkinter gui is not responding?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I monitor Tkinter buttons when Python is busy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376870/how-can-i-monitor-tkinter-buttons-when-python-is-busy)

I have a problem with tkinter gui code i wrote.It stops responding when i press a button and the function is executed.Here is an example code to make things clearer:

```
from Tkinter import*
import Tkinter as tk
import tkFileDialog
import urllib
import urllib2


list1 =["urls of video files"]


def run():
    for links1 in list1:
    text1.insert(str(list1.index(links1)+1)+'.end', 'video_'+str(list1.index(links1)+1)+'.mp4'+'.........Downloading')
        text1.update()#Update text widget
        urllib.urlretrieve(links1.split('\">')[0],'video_'+str(list1.index(links1)+1)+'.mp4')
        text1.insert(str(list1.index(links1)+1)+'.end','.....Finished\n')
        text1.yview(END)
    text1.insert(END,'>>All files have been downloaded.Enjoy ! ! !\n')


#Window Title    
app=Tk()
app.title("Title")
app.geometry('700x400+200+200')
app.resizable(0,0)



button=Button(app,text="Press me",font=("Times", 12, "bold"),width=20,borderwidth=5,command=run)
button.pack(padx=5,pady=8)


frame1 = Frame(app, width=600, height=200)
xframe1 = Frame(frame1, relief=RAISED, borderwidth=5)


text1 = Text(frame1,height = 3,font=("Times", 12))
text1.insert(END,"")
text1.pack(side=LEFT,fill=Y)


s_start = Scrollbar(frame1)
s_start.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)
s_start.config(command=text1.yview)
text1 .config(yscrollcommand=s_start.set)

Label(frame1, text='').place(relx=1.06, rely=0.125,anchor=CENTER)
frame1.pack()

app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is a duplicate, so look at the answers for the original. Short answer: the window needs the event loop to be running so that redraw events can be processed, but while your loop is running the event loop is stopped.

To answer the question in the comments:

the event loop is an infinite loop that runs when you call `mainloop`. It looks something like this:

```
while True:
    event = event_queue.pop()
    event.process()
```

(there isn't really a global object literally named event_queue, so don't go looking for it...)

When `run` is running, it is being run inside the imaginary `event.process()` method. When you update a widget from code such as inserting text, the widget is *not* immediately redrawn. Instead, a "redraw" event is added to the queue. However, while your `run` function is running, you are stuck in the `event.process()` portion of the event loop and thus no other events are being processed. Thus, no redrawing of the screen can happen until your function exits and the next event is pulled off the queue.

Now, if you run `update` in your function, it starts a *new* event loop and those events will be processed. This can be bad because you have a potentially infinite loop inside an infinite loop. If you call `update_idletasks`, however, it causes only the "idle" tasks to be processed. Redraw events fall into this category so they are processed, but things like button clicks and mouse movements are *not* processed.

Comment: hello,can you explain it a little more.which is the loop and which the event loop?Thanks.

Comment: so,the update_idletasks should replace my text.update() ?

Comment: Yes. You should almost never call 'update' unless you fully understand the consequences.

Comment: I have replaced text1.update() with text1.update_idletasks(),but the problem remains.Maybe there is another way?

Comment: I can't fully answer in a comment. Search this site, there are several questions and answers related to this problem. Bottom line is, there is no quick fix. You need to understand how the event loop works and then come up with a solution that works. You will either need to use multiple threads, multiple processes, or refactor your code to work in small chunks that wont block the event loop.